# how to start Android example project from command-line?

Tags: android

I dislike using Eclipse and wish to start an example Android project from the command-line, how can i do this? Is there a way to use "android create project" command to automatically pull in example code from the SDK? A similar method to the following perhaps?

```
android create project --package com.example.helloandroid \
--activity HelloAndroid \
--target 1 \
--path HelloAndroid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example how to build and run `ApiDemos` sample project.

1. Go to your SDK folder, then to `../samples/android-#/ApiDemos`, where # is API Level.
2. Start terminal in this folder.
3. Run `android list targets` and find target with API Level that is equal or higher then what you've chosen for # on step 1. Lets call this target X. In my case X equals 21. It looks like in your case X equals 1.
4. Run `android update project -p . -n ApiDemos -t X` (change X to correct value)
5. Run `ant debug`
6. Run `adb install bin/ApiDemos-debug.apk`

For Step 6 to succeed you need to connect your device to computer via USB. Make sure you've checked `Setting->Applications->Development->USB Debugging`. Also you can verify that `adb` can see your device running `adb devices` in the terminal.

Now sample project is built and installed on your device.