# Android studio: start project from command line

Tags: android

I have read a helpfull [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184654/how-to-start-android-example-project-from-command-line) however there is some things that are missing. I can create project from command line

```
android create project --gradle --gradle-version 0.12.2 \
--package com.test.test \
--activity TestActivity \
--target 1 \
--path AutoAndroidApp \
```

However, this does not create an identical structure as if I would create a project with the android studio. For example from GUI application is put in app folder, also there is build forlder and other differences.

Is there a way to actually reproduce the creation of the project from a command line?